# Email with Magento 2 and XAMPP with Gmail

Tags: email, magento, xampp, gmail, magento2

Hi i have Magento 2 installed on Xampp and when i continue with a purchase i do not get an email.  I am using a gmail account.  What i have done so far is below.

Updated all email settings in:
Stores - Configuration - Sales - Sales Emails
Stores - general - and all the general contacts
Stores - Advanced - System - host and port fields to smtp.gmail.com and have tried ports 587, 25 and 465
Updated my php.ini file Mail Function 
Updated my sendmail.ini file

Im not sure where to go from here.  It would help a lot if i can find at least a log somewhere of where my emails are going or why they are failing.  I have tried all the different ports and when i do i update it in all the files and the dashboard.  Im sorry if i have left anything out in advance.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?